# XcodeでObjective-Cプログラミング時にメソッドの候補が見たい場合

Tags: ios, xcode

メンバの候補は.を入力すれば出てくるのですが、メソッドの候補をはスペースを入力しても表示されないので、メソッドの候補が見れるやり方があれば知りたいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

レシーバの名称と「obj」とすると、

```
[obj
```

とスペースまで書いてから、escキーを押すと、メソッドの候補が表示されます。

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> で表示されます。

ただし、このキーバインドはOSXで「Spotlight検索を表示」が割り当てられており、そちらの優先度の方が高いため、キーボードのショートカット設定から無効にする必要があります。

[image: Mac使う時に真っ先にやる設定のひとつ]